# Dynamic search box radio button filter values using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a search box with radio button filters very like the yahoo search and filter elements where the user can refine there search by choosing on of the filters before searching.

When a user clicks on a filter I want a message to appear in the search box, such as "Search All", "Search broadband" etc.

I have it working mostly. If you click on each filter the message appears correctly. The problem I have is the (default) "Search All" message doesn't appear on page load.

below is the jQuery I have so far

```
$('.searchFilters label').click(function(){                                      
        var input = $('#searchId');                                      
        input.val('Search '+$(this).text()).addClass('empty');
    }); 
    $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
        var input = $('#searchId');
        if(input.hasClass('empty')){
            $('.searchFilters label').val('Enter search term');
            input.blur();
            $('#autocomplete').css({'display':'none'});         
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    });
    $('#searchId').click(function(){
        $(this).val('').removeClass('empty');   
        $('#autocomplete').css({'display':'block'});
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Where do you want the Search All all to show up? Maybe just put it in your HTML since it is used on page load anyway?

Comment: The Search All should only show when the "All" filter has been selected on page load. I can't have this in the HTML as it needs to be generated dynamically. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this question by adding the following piece of code and it all works fine now.

```
// injects "Search (label)" into search box on page load
// injects "Search (label)" into search box on main nav click
$('.searchFilters label').each(function(index){
    if($(this).attr('class')){                              
        $('#searchId').val('Search '+$(this).text());
    }   
});
```

Thanks for your help

The full script is:

```
// Sets the text for in the searchbox for the corresponding searchbox filter
;(function(){                                  
    // injects "Search (label)" into search box on page load
    // injects "Search (label)" into search box on main nav click
    $('.searchFilters label').each(function(index){
        if($(this).attr('class')){                              
            $('#searchId').val('Search '+$(this).text());
        }   
    });

    // injects "Search (label)" into search box on filter click
    $('.searchFilters label').click(function(){                                      
        var input = $('#searchId');                                      
        input.val('Search '+$(this).text()).addClass('empty');      
    }); 

    // Stops form submitting if "Search label" is displayed in search box
    $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
        var input = $('#searchId');
        if(input.hasClass('empty')){
            $('.searchFilters label').val('Enter search term');
            input.blur();
            $('#autocomplete').css({'display':'none'});         
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Clears search box onclick
    $('#searchId').click(function(){
        $(this).val('').removeClass('empty');   
        $('#autocomplete').css({'display':'block'});
        $(this).focus();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function to handle page load.

Just set the input field's value inside the ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.searchFilters label').click(function(){                                      
        var input = $('#searchId');                                      
        input.val('Search '+$(this).text()).addClass('empty');
    }); 
    $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
        var input = $('#searchId');
        if(input.hasClass('empty')){
            $('.searchFilters label').val('Enter search term');
            input.blur();
            $('#autocomplete').css({'display':'none'});         
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    });
    $('#searchId').click(function(){
        $(this).val('').removeClass('empty');   
        $('#autocomplete').css({'display':'block'});
    });

    // Get the selected item and execute a fake click on it's label
    $('.searchFilters input[type=radio]:checked').parent().click();
});
```

I'm assuming the radio button resides inside the `label` tag.

I haven't tested this code, but it should give you an indication.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I forgot to mention that the filters are attached and mirror the main navigation. 

So if you click on the main navigation for say "Broadband" the filter for "Broadband" is automatically selected. 

Your code above still sets "Search all" to the search box on page load no matter what filter is selected when it should say "Search broadband". Sorry about that and thank you for your answer.

Comment: I updated my code assuming the radio buttons reside inside the `label` tags.

Comment: Hi Gerrit. Thanks for your answer. I got the issue fixed with the updated code that I posted.